# How to access object variables made from constructors

Tags: java, fxml

Im have 2 buttons, 1 uses the constructor class in for round1rock, while the other 1 tries to access those parameters. What is wrong with my code?

Constructor Class

```
public ROCK(int hp, int stamina, int attack, int speed, String type){
   this.hp=hp;  
   this.stamina= stamina;
   this.attack= attack;
   this.speed = speed;
   this.type = type;
}
```

2 buttons:

```
private void continueRound1 (ActionEvent event){
       ROCK round1Rock= new ROCK( 500, 100, 100, 100, "Metamorphic");
    }
    private void Attack (ActionEvent event){
        round1Rock.hp = 12;

    }
```

how do i  access the previously made object?

Comment: Define `ROCK round1Rock` on class level

Answer (score 3):

When you define

```
private void continueRound1 (ActionEvent event){
   ROCK round1Rock= new ROCK( 500, 100, 100, 100, "Metamorphic");
}
```

You are defining `ROCK round1Rock` just for the function `continueRound1`.
For `Attack` to access that object, you need to define `round1Rock` on a class level.

Try:

```
ROCK round1Rock = null;

private void continueRound1 (ActionEvent event){
  round1Rock= new ROCK( 500, 100, 100, 100, "Metamorphic");
}
private void Attack (ActionEvent event){
    round1Rock.hp = 12;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Define round1Rock on class level ,

```
class someclass

{

   private ROCK round1Rock;


          -----

   private void continueRound1 (ActionEvent event){
       round1Rock= new ROCK( 500, 100, 100, 100, "Metamorphic");
    }


    private void Attack (ActionEvent event){
        round1Rock.hp = 12;

    }

           ------
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all declare instance of ROCK as global like this

```
private ROCK round1Rock = null;
private void continueRound1 (ActionEvent event){
       round1Rock= new ROCK( 500, 100, 100, 100, "Metamorphic");
    }

    private void Attack (ActionEvent event){
        round1Rock.hp = 12;

    }
```

The second thing inside your Attack action listener you may not access variable hp because it maybe private so it's better to create setter and getter methods for your Rock class then use this.

Rock Class:

```
public ROCK(int hp, int stamina, int attack, int speed, String type){
   this.hp=hp;  
   this.stamina= stamina;
   this.attack= attack;
   this.speed = speed;
   this.type = type;
}

public void setHP(int hp){
   this.hp = hp
}

public void getHP(){
  return hp;
}
```

Then in your other class use this:

```
 private void Attack (ActionEvent event){
            round1Rock.setHP(12); //this will update the value

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a new Rock object in continueRound1 method. You can create the new Rock object in a class scope and set the private access. This will resolves your question.

**Additional Tip:** You are creating a new object on every button clicks. This will cause to ***OutOfMemoryError*** if I write a program to click the button indefinitely.

Following are my insights to avoid this issue:

1. I assume every client requires new rock. So, create an Empty Rock object in the client class.
2. In your Client constructor, you can initialize the rock object with default values by the rock type. The getDefaultRockForType will helps you to create as many rock type you want. So, we hide the implementation details of rock object with some values in client class to standardized value in Rock class.

Here's my code snippet:

```
Class Client {
       private Rock round1Rock =  new Rock();
       Client() {
          round1Rock = round1Rock.getDefaultRockForType("Metamorphic"); 
       }
       private void continueRound1 (ActionEvent event){
            round1Rock= round1Rock.getDefaultRockForType("Metamorphic");
       }

    private void Attack (ActionEvent event){
        round1Rock.setHp(12);

    }
}
```

In your Rock class, you can give your default values decided by your rock type.

Class Rock:

```
public Rock getDefaultRockForType(String type){
   if(type.equals("Metamorphic")){
         this.hp=500;  
         this.stamina= 100;
         this.attack= 100;
         this.speed = 100;
         this.type = type;
   }
}
```